# Search on multiple values

Tags: design-patterns, algorithms, database, sql-server

I have a database having around 15 tables.Currently I am working on a report generation page, which is having 16 criteria.The values are distributed among multiple tables.User can select any number of search criteria. The problem is, if the user is entering 2-3 values, it is better to filter first by certain value and then apply the next level of filtration on remaining values and this order of filtration depends on the user input always. That means, I have to check all the possible ways of input permutation and give execution path for each, which will be horrible.Is there any way by which I can reduce the execution paths. I am not able to come up with an efficient algorithm.

Suppose I have 3 parameters: `name`, `skill`, `programExp`

If `name` is given, then I should filter based on `name` first.
If `skill` is given, then I should filter using `skill`, `programExp` and then `name`.

Comment: Can you give a (reduced) example of the problem you face? It is not entirely clear.<br/> Do you mean that if you have search criteria `A`, `B` and `C`, then if all three are given, you should filter on `A` first, but if it is `A+B` or `A+C`, the you should filter on `A` last?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, you should give some more details and examples. For a maybe similar problem I have used Apache Solr and its facet queries successfully. But if this would work for you is difficult to say, since it depends on the search criteria and what results you need.

Comment: I have added one small example

Comment: Is doing this with database queries mandatory for some reason? I would really put these values in a Solr Document, flatten the data structure that way and then query with Solr. Not only for speed, but the resulting code would be far less complex. Your example doesn't help very much. If these would be in one table, it would be a very simple query and even with multiple tables optimizing the order of queries would mostly become interesting if you have very large tables.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the results of your query are, essentially, several of your tables joined and the rows winnowed down using a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go on the assumption that the query results are the results of a `JOIN` filtered using a `WHERE` clause.

> I have to check all the possible ways of input permutation and give
>   execution path for each, which will be horrible.

That will be horrible.  It sounds like you're trying to do something any decent database already does for you.

Good databases have a *query optimizer* whose job it is to examine incoming queries and come up with an *execution plan* for carrying it out.  Plans are constructed to consume the fewest resources (CPU, memory, access to storage) while answering queries quickly and correctly.  The major factors that go into these decisions are the tables used, `JOIN` conditions, `WHERE` clauses, available indexes and table statistics.  For example, if the optimizer sees that one of your `WHERE` clauses can cut the result set of a `JOIN` from a billion rows to, say, a thousand, that condition will be applied earlier rather than later so fewer intermediate results have to be handled.

What this means for you is that you don't have to worry about what order you apply the conditions.  Stack them up in a `WHERE` clause and the optimizer will take care of the rest.  Once you've made it work and work right, you can worry about making it work fast *if you've determined that your queries are a bottleneck*.  The cure will almost universally not be trying to outsmart the optimizer or handling the data yourself, it will be tuning your database so the optimizer has what it needs to do a better job.  Databases with optimizers often have an `EXPLAIN` or `SHOW PLAN` feature that will let you see what the optimizer comes up with for a given query, and the parts that cause performance problems will  stick out like a sore thumb.

Bottom line:  build a query based on the conditions in force and let the database do its job.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be coding an “Sql execution Path\Plan decision tree”

**You need to optimize your Query (singular) to perform as best it can with NO criteria. Then add a Dynamic where clause encompassing all the selected search criteria.**

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in a comment, a search index is a better solution that database queries. I can second the Thorsten's suggestion of apache Solr. You could probably get a working index up in an hour.

Comment: ...and then must develop a way to keep the index in sync with the database.

Comment: @Blrfl - not a problem, Solr already has mechanisms for this